# Tesseract ios with trained data

Tags: ios, iphone, ocr, tesseract

Is there any way to include trained data into the tesseract ios library ?
following this guide 
http://michaeljaylissner.com/posts/2012/02/11/adding-new-fonts-to-tesseract-3-ocr-engine/

doesn't lead to anywhere with the repo I'm currently using 
https://github.com/gali8/Tesseract-OCR-iOS

I need to know how to include the trained data into the above ios repo..
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Download tessdata as a zip from github . For example if you are trying english or France use this one: https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata 
Then unzip it in your local. Drag and drop the "tessdata" folder from your local onto the XCode project. Make sure to to check "Copy Items if needed" and check "Create folder references" when you drag. Build and test.

For those who want to install from scratch. Follow this tutorial:
https://www.raywenderlich.com/163445/tesseract-ocr-tutorial-ios